# 'title' is undefined while generating sitemap in Astro

Tags: javascript, sitemap, astrojs

I want to generate a dynamic sitemap but it is showing undefined value for the `post.frontmatter.title`, what shall I do to fix this?

Error: [image: Error]

Code for `sitemap.xml.js`,

```js
import { Feed } from "feed";
import { getAllPosts } from "../lib/posts";

export async function get(){
    const feed = new Feed({
        title: "dhairyashah.vercel.app",
        description: "I am 16 years old and I share and write articles on Web Development, Programming, and Technology.",
        id: "https://dhairyashah.vercel.app/",
        link: "https://dhairyashah.vercel.app/sitemap.xml",
        language: "en",
        image: "https://dhairyashah.vercel.app/assets/profile-pic.png",
        favicon: "https://dhairyashah.vercel.app/assets/profile-pic.png",
        author: {
            name: "Dhairya Shah",
            email: "dhairyashah.work@gmail.com",
        },
        feedLinks: {
            rss: "https://dhairyashah.vercel.app/sitemap.xml",
            atom: "https://dhairyashah.vercel.app/sitemap.xml",
        },
    })
    const allPosts = (await getAllPosts())

allPosts.forEach((post) => {
    feed.addItem({
        title: post.frontmatter.title,
        id: `https://dhairyashah.vercel.app/posts/${post.url}`,
        link: `https://dhairyashah.vercel.app/posts/${post.url}`,
        content: post.frontmatter.description,
    });
})

return { body: feed.rss2() }
}
```

Code for `../lib/posts.js`,

```js
async function load() {
  const fetchedPosts = import.meta.glob('../pages/posts/*.mdx', { eager: true });

  const getPost = async (key) => {
    const url = key.replace('../pages/posts/', '/').replace('.mdx', '/');
    const awaitedPost = await fetchedPosts[key].default();
    const item = {

      ...awaitedPost.props.frontmatter,
      url,
      key,
    }
    return item;
  };

  const mappedPosts = Object.keys(fetchedPosts).map((key) => {
    const awaitedPost = getPost(key);
    return awaitedPost;
  });

  const results = await Promise.all(mappedPosts);
  return results;
}

let _posts;

export async function getAllPosts() {
  _posts = _posts || load();

  return await _posts;
}
```

What can be do so that I can generate the site map without getting undefined error?

Comment: Have you tried `post.title` instead? Since you're using the spread operator on `prop.frontmatter` you should be able to access `title` directly.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

I got this working

- the main issue you had is the usage of the `{eager: true}` option in `import.meta.glob` which then no longer require an await because the content is 'eagerly' imported already.

Reference: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import

- then as pointed out by stevenw00 you also need to match the post spread to the usage `frontmatter` to be selected in one place, so it's enough with `...awaitedPost,`

## Fix

```js
async function load() {
  const fetchedPosts = import.meta.glob('../pages/posts/*.mdx', { eager: true });

  const getPost = async (key) => {
    const url = key.replace('../pages/posts/', '/').replace('.mdx', '/');
    const awaitedPost = fetchedPosts[key];
    const item = {
      ...awaitedPost,
      url,
      key,
    }
    return item;
  };
```

## Example

Just for the sake of this question, I placed the fix in a minified example to provide a functional reference https://github.com/MicroWebStacks/astro-examples/blob/7d3d634a198390a88ce7bd4a46a9d47a226f8f55/22_mdx-svg/src/libs/posts.js#L9